# UIAlertView display an informative statement with OK

Tags: cocoa, iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit, uialertview

I want to display a UIAlert to indicate to my users that something went wrong (maybe no Internet). I just need an OK button.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [looking in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-SW13)?

Comment: I did and I was a little confused

UIAlertView *startAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"string" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:@"Button2", nil];

Can I leave out the otherButtonTitles?